# How to get inner and outer width to a single element?

Tags: jquery, css, width

Is there a way in CSS or jQuery to get inner and outer width to a **single element**?
I have a div that has a `width` of `100%` and a `height` of `30px`, and inside this div i have a navigation menu list (two unordered lists). I want to get `inner width` of `960px` to this div so that the menu will be centered and the background of the div will have a width:100% because the div has a width of 100%.

example:
[image: Inner and outer width]

I don't want to add any other div inside or outside this div. I want do all this with this **single div**. How can i accomplish this?

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
div{
width:100%;
height:30px;
border:1px solid red;/* for fiddle visualization*/}

ul{  
margin:0;
height:30px; 
width:430px;
position: relative;   

}
div ul:first-of-type{
background-color:#00f;/* for fiddle visualization*/
left: 50%;
margin-left: -430px; 
float: left;
}
div ul:nth-of-type(2){
background-color:#0f0;/* for fiddle visualization*/
right: 50%;
margin-right: -430px; 
float: right;

}
```

here is a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/FKZx5/

Answer (score 1):

```
div {
   width: 100%;
   background: url("...");
}
    div ul {
        margin: 0px auto;
        width: 960px;
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I did not explain myself well. There is two <ul> inside my div. Thank you so much for answer.

Answer (score 1):

firstly:
if you only trying to achive the centering issue, add `text-align:center;` to the div.
you dont need to play with the width.

secondly:
why dont you wand to add a second layer div with `width: 960px;`?